# Google Sheets - LOOKUP through unique string

Tags: google-sheets

After watching tutorials over at YouTube and seeing all of them uses a unique ID number in their examples, I now ask here if there's a way to get the price from a string lookup query.

Link for viewing:

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/...](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OF9c1Y7ygmXjq_2Tfuyd5sTFIZj0lPaM_W45RsfkA9U/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @player0 edited

Comment: @player0, yes through its name not by id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this in **Sheet2!B2** (after you delete everything in **Sheet2!B2:B** range)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet1!B:C, 2, 0), ))
```

[image]